Are there philosophers who argue that mental states are in a many-to-one relationship to physical states?
The following is a philosophical position that I find quite appealing, and I'm wondering if there are any philosophers who actively argue for it, i.e. does the following view have a name?
We start by saying that there might be many different mental phenomena that are compatible with the same physical states. So I might be writing this because I am a conscious being, or because I am a P-zombie, or because I am a conscious being but with an inverted spectrum etc., and the premise is that there might be no possible way for someone else to experimentally determine which is the case. I know that there are philosophers who hold this part of the position, though certainly not everyone does.
The next part is that, having decided these things are all possible, we then say that all of them are true. After all, If it's really true that I'd behave the same if I perceived red as green and green as red (and had done since birth)*, then how do I know there isn't another me who perceives things that way, inhabiting the same body as me and writing the same text as me right now? When that person writes red they mean what I understand as green and vice versa, but they still write exactly the same thing, and so the existence of those other perceptions doesn't contradict the simultaneous existence of mine.
So the idea is that my mental states are not unique - there are other mental states that supervene on the same physical states at the same time. I perceive my mental states as a single, unique unbroken thread, but that's only because these different mental states don't interact with one another.
My point here isn't to argue for this view but to ask if there are people who do argue for it in the literature. Are there?
To clarify: I'm intending to talk here about things like qualia that are held (by some) to be unmeasurable in principle. The question isn't intended to be about multiple observable consequences of the same observable physical thing, which is what I think a lot of the comments are addressing. Rather, I'm trying to address a view that I think is fairly common, namely that qualia (i) exist, (ii) are epiphenominal in the sense that they have no causal effect on the physical world at all, and (iii) are not completely determined by the physical world, in the sense that they could in principle ("conceivably") be different from how they are, or absent entirely, without this having any observable effect. I'm saying that if you believe all three of these then it's consistent to also believe that it's possible for a person to have multiple completely separate epiphenomenal consciousnesses at the same time, which both supervene on the same physical state and which don't interact with each other. Rather than being a problem for epiphenomenalism I think this would actually be quite a reasonable position, and so the question is whether there is anyone who explicitly argues for it.
*I don't think this particular claim about colours is actually true, but that doesn't matter for the argument - it might be that my perceptions could be shifted around in some more subtle way such that it is true.

Hilary Putnam, “multiple realizability”! (is the inverse: same mental state from multiple physical ones)

Multiple realizability is quite popular, it is the basis of functionalism about minds. But 'reverse multiple relaizability' that you suggest is almost never discussed. The only instance I know is Pukhaev's 2013 thesis, p. 74, and even he is purely hypothetical and very brief. Probably because mental states are hard to 'measure' with any precision and differentiating them reliably is a tricky and highly speculative business when the physical effect is the same.

@Conifold thanks, that reference is appreciated. It would be appropriate to post it as an answer

It does seem pretty weird that it's not discussed though. If you want to accept multiple realizability without also accepting reverse multiple realizability, then it seems like you'd need a good argument for why it must be a one-to-many relationship rather than a many-to-many one. In the absence of such an argument, the view I presented seems unavoidable.

It is not so much that people want to accept one without the other but rather that examples of (direct) multiple realizability are much more tangible and easy to set up, and they already highlight the challenges of naive functionalism. So there is no need to go into more speculative and controversial waters. Philosophical zombies and inverted spectra are rather exotic niche topics remote from mainstream functional modeling of the mind.

Well yeah, but exotic, niche topics are what I'm here to ask about.

Then you have come to the right place! Wade in. Just, keep those hearing protectors on, because it can get pretty loud.

All dualists and neutral monists who hold by causal closure of the physical are susceptible to the sort of qualia multiplicity you postulate. And if any of them hold by the Many World Interpretation of QM, then they should reasonably expect your multiplicity to be realized.  So your thinking is not off the wall.
Additionally, the Evolutionary Test Case for causal consciousness, which was spelled out as a refuting test case for all Identity Theories that fail necessity identity tests by William James and Karl Popper, among others, points out that if IT theories rely upon token-token rather than type-type identity, then evolutionary variance will spawn just the sort of variability between individuals that you postulate. And as qualia are non causal in these theories, the variance would lead to irrelevant, inappropriate, or no qualia in association with a brain function.  The test case is pointing out this has not happened, therefore the premise is wrong.  But the point of the test case is that the theory of causal closure allows just the variance you propose.  At least between individuals.
However, despite this being a possible POV, I have not seen any philosophers advocate for it.  I would suspect this is so because we DO see correlation between neurons and thoughts, and a theory of mind that explicitly predicts otherwise is not going to find many advocates.
You could push back on this argument, and note that the evolutionary test case shows ALL Identity Theories and neutral monisms have this problem, but most of their advocates are either unaware of the evolutionary test case, or find some rationalization to deny it.
Little of this yet addresses your question about whether multiple versions of yourself with diverse qualia are being carried along epiphenomenally by your body, so I will try to complete a connection.  If your scenario were the case for the rest of us, most of your readers would have non relevant qualia, and most of us would agree with you, silently.  But for me, I only have relevant qualia, and all the others who post here do too.  So there is no reason to think any of us, you included, have this multiple selves with diversity of qualia.

Your position seems to be a special case of:
2 different causality chains can lead to the same effect.
or
2 different paths can lead to the same destination.
It is well known to be true and there is no need to split it into the mental domain and the physical domain.
It works on mental X mental, mental X physical and physical X physical domain.
However, it does not follow that each thing arriving at the same destination must have taken a different path. There will be a specific distribution between a few different taken paths, where some were used more times than others. Usually the paths of low resistance/requirements.
So, there likely will be other people who see red the same way as you do internally.

If you don't want to generalize the concept and stay at your special case, then look for "multiple realizability" as others already suggested. Although, it states the opposite way. Maybe somewhere it hides a statement about the reverse case.

It seems you just shifted "multiple realizability" from
2 different physical brains may create same mind.
to
2 different minds may create same actions.
You did not reverse it. Both should work.
